# IE9 this = DispHTMLWindow2 inside a prototype's function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I created an extension function called startsWith in my general js.

It goes like this:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
 if (this.indexOf(str) == 0) {
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

When running in IE9 i get an error saying: "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'".

When looking in the debugger it seems like this is DispHTMLWindow2.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: This works for me in IE9. http://jsfiddle.net/sQt5C/

Comment: How are you calling it? Sounds like it's being called as a function, not a method.

Comment: Sounds like you are not passing in a string. you could add a constructor check to stop it bugging out  if (this.constructor !== String) return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following as taken from [this site](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6620)

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match("^"+str)==str)}

String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match(str+"$")==str)}

String.prototype.trim = function(){return 
(this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""))}
```

Comment: RegExp is a little overkill for `startsWith` and `endsWith`.  Not to mention that they would both break if `str` contains a special character.